# Update field of another model from cutomized View in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I want to update inventory quantity from my customized view in odoo 11 and want to do it by using automated action in odoo studio but have no clue how to write python code in automated actions.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post your view and make an attempt at solving the problem; without a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it'll be difficult to resolve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For AUTOMATION:

Go to Settings, then

- Go to Technical then (Make sure debug mode is on otherwise u wont see it)
- Scroll down and Select Schedule or Automate Action
- For python code select Execute Python Code and perform like that(I ve selected Schedule one and other Automation option is also same with some difference i hope u will resolve your scenario):

[image]

**P.S** model.to_submittt() is the function written by me in python odoo module which is installed here.

Module example in pic:

[image]